# docker-compose exec web python manage.py makemigrations problem

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

## Problem

I created a new Django project and tried to change the database from default to PostgreSQL. After changing the `DATABASES` in settings.py, I tried to run `python manage.py migrate` in local environment and docker-compose containers. While it worked ok in local settings, the docker-compose didn't. It throws `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'`. error. So, is there any way to fix this?

## Steps to replicate the error

OS: WSL Ubuntu 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft

1. `docker-compose up -d`
2. `docker-compose exec web pipenv install psycopg2-binary==2.8.4`
3. `docker-compose down`
4. `docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate`

## Database settings and Docker Files

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'Bardwolf@314',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

### My docker-compose.yml, Dockerfile

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/

RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
RUN pipenv run pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.4

COPY . /code/
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
        volumes:
            - ./code
        
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - db
        
    db:
        image: postgres:11
```

Comment: `docker-compose down`  will delete all of your configs you made in docker exec ....

Answer (score 1):

Your Django running inside the `web` container so you need to go into that container to run django commands.

So when you run `docker-compose down` after exec install it will remove previous container

After you run docker-compose up

Just run the other 2 commands and don't run `docker-compose down`

if you want to run it manually

You can go into the container bash by:

> docker-compose exec web /bin/bash

Once you are in the console then you can type:

> python3 manage.py makemigrations

If you want to exit container bash shell just type `exit`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way...

```sh
docker-compose exec web sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations --noinput"
```